Can child processes create shared memory and share it with parent processes?
Can a child process create a SharedMemory object and share it with a parent process? Currently I am getting errors when I try. I need this because creating and copying memory is the major performance bottleneck in my application, but I need to write the shared memory in the parent process.
Here are three minimal examples illustrating the issue. I use time.sleep(1) to control whether the parent or child process completes first.
Case 1 (no error): Create shared memory in parent process, share with child
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Process
def worker():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test")

shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test", create=True, size=1)
Process(target=worker).start()
time.sleep(1)
shm.unlink()

Case 2 (no error): Creating shared memory in child process, not sharing with parent
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Process
def worker():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test", create=True, size=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    shm.unlink()

Process(target=worker).start()

Case 3 (ERROR): Create shared memory in child process, share with parent
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Process
def worker():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test", create=True, size=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    shm.unlink()


Process(target=worker).start()
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test")

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/benjamin/Documents/duckit/covin.py", line 24, in <module>
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name="test")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/benjamin/miniforge3/envs/hichdev/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._fd = _posixshmem.shm_open(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/test'

Motivation:
I'm trying to use numpy loadtxt in a numer of child processes over a bunch of files (a CPU-bottlenecked, not I/O-bottlenecked task, hence being done with multiprocessing). Then I want to write the arrays to an HDF5 file, which is most efficient when done sequentially in the main thread. If the arrays must be copied for the parent process to receive them (as when passing then via a multiprocessing queue or returning them), then this becomes the performance bottleneck for the whole program. Hence, I want to copy the arrays into shared memory in the child processes and share them with the parent process in order to write them.

Your question is unclear, to me at least. Your code is also incomplete. You show 3 examples - why? The first appears to cause no error, so why don't you use that? Why are you adding two more examples that do cause errors?

Only the third example caused an error, as stated, and it is the approach I need to use, for reasons I explained in the “motivation” section. To repeat, allocating and copying memory is the main performance bottleneck to the program I am implementing, so I want to do that in a child process and share with the main process. My question is the title of the post - can you clarify what you find unclear about it? I tried adding some edits which perhaps disambiguate further.

The answer is that any Python process can share memory with any other Python process regardless of how the two were started and what their hierarchical relationship is. Show the minimal code necessary to demonstrate fully what you are actually trying to do and what aspect doesn't work. There's no need to show something that does work but isn't what you want.

@MarkSetchell My goal is to understand why the third example I shared fails.

Ok, so make your third example a proper [mcve] with import statements and everything necessary for folk to run it.

@MarkSetchell Done.

You have a race condition. What if your main program tries to attach the shared memory before the child has created it?

@MarkSetchell has it - look at the order of operations. Can you think of an order of execution where the shared memory is unlinked before the main process tries to access it?

Please consider upvoting and/or accepting @MarkTolonen answer if it helped you out.

Non-working case has a race condition if the parent tries to connect to the memory first.  You can use events to let parent/child know the state of the shared memory and then there is no need for sleeps:
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as sm

def worker(ready, done):
    shm = sm.SharedMemory(name="test", create=True, size=1)
    shm.buf[0] = 123
    ready.set()  # Let parent know shared memory is set up
    done.wait()  # Wait for parent to finish with shared memory
    shm.unlink()

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Idiom to work with both Linux and Windows
    ready = mp.Event()
    done = mp.Event()
    mp.Process(target=worker, args=(ready, done), daemon=True).start()
    ready.wait()  # Wait for child to set up shared memory
    shm = sm.SharedMemory(name="test")
    print(shm.buf[0])
    done.set()  # Let child know parent is finished with shared memory

Output:
123

